# Developing an Android phone app -- can I use an Android tablet to test it on?

Tags: android, tablet

I've developed a couple of Enterprise iOS apps for our users in the field. Some have expressed a preference for Android devices over Apple, and I fully understand. I do not have an Android phone, nor do I want to get one and have a second account to maintain. I'm wondering if I can use an inexpensive Android tablet to reliably test an application that will ultimately be running on an Android phone? The app will need to communicate via internet to a server via cell connection or wifi.

Also, any advice for an Android newbie developer would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a phone on Wifi, no need to maintain a second account. If there's a budgetary issue, a used Nexus 4 shouldn't run more than $150 -- cheaper than a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could test on a Android tablet but it would be hard to see how it render on a phone.

You could also use the Android Emulator to test different size and android configuration.

Comment: Thank you Rousseau. The Android SDK is currently downloading so I will soon see what options are available for me. I wish I could mark both yours and Matt's answer as the right answers. I really appreciate the help. P.S., nice picture. Last time I saw the Eiffel Tower was in 1979. Gives you an idea how old I am.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I developed my first major Android app using only a couple of cheap tablet devices. It's fine; the only thing you can't really test is "what happens to my app when a phone call comes in." Plus if you can get the emulator working under HAXM, or some other similar setup where it doesn't work like a tortoise trapped in amber, you can test on a variety of simulated devices perfectly well.

Other things to consider:

- You'll probably want to test your app on a variety of different hardware and Android versions, in particular I'd recommend testing on older devices. This means that you friends' old Android phones are a great source of cheap test devices. I regularly gather phones from friends that would otherwise just end up lingering in the back of a drawer as a "spare" that will never actually get used. Bear in mind that you can use all the features of a phone apart from the actual phone bit without a SIM, including a WiFi-based data connection.
- You may find that you can find good, contract-free "pay as you go" phone SIMs. I use a provider whose "credits" don't expire, so I have a phone connection for my test devices where there's no ongoing cost, apart from the actual calls I make when testing.

Comment: Thank you Matt. May I ask what contract-free provider you are using? That sounds like a workable solution when I'm ready to test on an actual phone. And yes, I can probably get my hands on an old no-longer-used Android.

Comment: Ah, OK. Guess I'll have to move to the UK. Will see if I can get the expense approval for that. Haven't been there since 1979 either.